# Publishing Service (Core to Master Publish)

Tags: publishing, publishing-service, module

We've just recently installed the Sitecore Publishing Service v3.1.4 and into our 9.0.2 setup of Sitecore. Currently Master to Web publishes work great but I'm unable to publish from Core to Master. Referencing their documentation it looks like out of the box only Master is a valid source within the sc.publishing.xml. Beyond that I'm not sure from the perspective of the Core database how to migrate changes to the Master database.

Any documentation that could help get us past this would be fantastic.

Thanks,

Tyler

Comment: You can't publish from `core` to `master` that's not how publishing works. The `core` database doesn't contain anything to publish and master is not a valid publishing target. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342755/what-is-the-difference-between-sitecores-core-master-and-web-databases) to see what those databases are for.

Comment: Hi Richard, yah been a bit since back in the swing of things with Sitecore. Trying to do some edits to the media link editor to put in a custom target (Download) but yah just totally spaced on this one. Thanks for the quick review!